# XSLT - Recursive grouping / count based on attribute values

Tags: xslt

I'm struggling with a simple recursive count problem based on distinct values. From a list such as:

```
<List>
    <Place continent="Asia" country="India" region="UP">Lucknow</Place>
    <Place continent="Europe" country="France" region="Provence">Marseille</Place>
    <Place continent="Europe" country="Greece" region="Arcadia">Dimitsana</Place>
    <Place continent="Europe" country="Italy" region="Sicily">Sicily</Place>
    <Place continent="Asia" country="India" region="Maharastra">Pune</Place>
    <Place continent="Asia" country="China">China</Place>
    <Place continent="Europe" country="France" region="Provence">Marseille</Place>
    <Place continent="America" country="Brasil" region="Pará">Belém</Place>
</List>
```

I'd like to retrieve an output based on distinct values for the continent, country and region attributes (in some cases optional), that would count recursively each token, as follows:

```
<Places>
<continent name="America" count="1">
    <country name="Brasil" count="1">
        <region name="Pará" count="1">
            <city name="Belém" count="1"/>
        </region>
    </country>
</continent>
<continent name="Asia" count="3">
    <country name="India" count="2">
        <region name="Maharastra" count="1">
            <city name="Pune" count="1"/>
        </region>
        <region name="UP" count="1">
            <city name="Lucknow" count="1"/>
        </region>
    </country>
    <country name="China" count="1"/>
</continent>
<continent name="Europe" count="4">
    <country name="France" count="2">
        <region name="Provence" count="2">
            <city name="Marseille" count="2"/>
        </region>
    </country>
    <country name="Greece" count="1">
        <region name="Arcadia" count="1">
            <city name="Dimitsana" count="1"/>
        </region>
    </country>
    <country name="Italy" count="1">
        <region name="Sicily" count="1"/>
    </country>
</continent>
```

I can manage to retrieve each set of distinct values (continents, countries, regions) independently, with, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="List">
    <Places> 
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Place" group-by="@continent"> 
            <continent>
                <xsl:attribute name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@continent"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="count">
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </continent> 
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Places>
```

— but, although I suppose I'm missing something very basic, I can't manage to get the nested grouping and count for countries inside continents, etc. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Inside of one for-each-group you can use another one of e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="@country"><country name="{current-grouping-key()}" count="{count(current-group()}"><xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="region">...</xsl:for-each-group></country></xsl:for-each-group>`.

Comment: Thank you! I just didn't think of using current group recursively. Quite stupid of me.